# Google Maps SDK - Swift 4 - markerInfoWindow does not show popover like arrow at bottom

Tags: swift4, google-maps-sdk-ios, xcode10, ios12

I am using google maps sdk in my project. I want to make the custom marker as given image.

1.Curve corners from top and bottom

2.Pop over like effect from bottom.

[image]

Case 1: Using below delegate method:

1.Curve corners from top and bottom - not done

2.Pop over like effect from bottom - done be default

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?
```

Case 2: Using below delegate method:

1.Curve corners from top and bottom - done

2.Pop over like effect from bottom - not done

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?
```

Now am not getting the proper way to tackle this problem? Any help appreciated a lot. Thanks in advance!!!